# How to plot a phase portrait for system of differential equations in mathematica or R?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, mathematica

Please, help me. I'd like the phase portrait for this system:

[image]

If anyone can make this portrait and post a print screen here, I would thank you very much.

Comment: This might be of interest: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14160/plotting-a-phase-portrait

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Online and free](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=streamplot%7B%7B-2x*ln%28x%2Fy%29%2C-y%2B5sqrt%28xy%29-3yx%5E%282%2F3%29%7D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C5%7D%2C%7By%2C0%2C5%7D%7D) (but using neither Mathematica nor R), the code

$$\texttt{streamplot{{-2x*ln(x/y),-y+5sqrt(xy)-3yx^(2/3)},{x,0,5},{y,0,5}}}$$
produces the diagram:

[image]

The fixed point in the middle is a stable node (sink), it might attract every trajectory starting from some $V(0)>0$, $K(0)>0$, and it is located at $$\left(\frac8{3\sqrt3},\frac8{3\sqrt3}\right)\approx(1.5396,1.5396).$$